# How can a Canadian establish US credit score

Tags: united-states, canada, credit-score

I don't have a SSN or US address.

I would like to start establishing a credit score in US. What are my options? What is the fastest way?

Comment: Why would you ever need a credit score in a country you have nothing to do with?

Comment: Nothing currently. But I plan to in the future. In the future if I need to get a mortgage, I will need a credit score. If I start now then it'll be ready when I need a mortgage. It's too bad they can't just pull my Canadian credit score and convert it to US credit score.

Comment: This is more of an expatriates SE question. See [this](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-to-build-credit-history-in-the-usa) answer, for example.

Comment: You'll need a US SSN for credit score.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. As far as I know, a person's SS is the only way to establish credit. This is the first thing they ask whenever you apply for any service in the US.

Answer (score 1):

1) The easy way is to find a job and they will assign you an SSN.

2) Here's the hard way.  If you're Canadian, open a TD Boarderless account in the U.S.  Put a small investment into any investment that would generate some type of income, such as capital gain, dividends, interest and etc...  Then you will need to file a US tax return to declare your income if you receive U.S. tax slips (although you're likely below the min filing requirement) at year end.  To file a U.S. tax return, you may  need what's called an ITIN or individual tax id number.  With the ITIN, you can get credit from the US TD boarderless account (only).  Consider getting a prepaid US credit card with the TD account to futher build credit at that specific bank.  It's not much credit, but you do start with creating a history.

Answer (score 0):

set up a US company (WY is cheap and easy), go south and open a personal and business bank account, ask for the itin form. file for the itin. set up your EIN for the company. get a credit card for both. pay some mail forwarding service with it. file for taxes in the next year using your itin. prepaid cards do not link to your tax id