# Is it possible to start building a credit score in the US from abroad?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, italy

I am an Italian citizen looking to move to the United States at some point next year; my fiancée submitted a petition for a K-1 Visa and we're waiting for it to be processed.

I have done a little reading on how credit score works in the US and I think I have a decent idea of what I can do once I have my Visa and have moved.

That being said, is there anything I can do prior to that while still in Italy, to start building a credit score? Also, I've had a prepaid card (maximum amount allowed on it is €10000) for almost 10 years now, and more recently opened an account with debit card: is there any way I can transfer that history to the US?

Comment: "*I've had a prepaid card ... for almost 10 years now*"  Prepaid cards do not affect your credit score, since there's no credit involved.

Comment: I'm slightly confused: I get that, yet there seems to be some confusion online: some sources suggest prepaid credit cards to start building a credit score; some specify that only some prepaid cards build one's credit score; some yet say that there is absolutely no way to build credit with prepaid cards.

Do you know for certain that the latter is in fact the truth?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no such thing as a **prepaid** *credit* card, by the very definition of what the word "credit" means (buy now, pay later). This is in contrast to a prepaid card, which a *stored value* ("pay now, buy later") card.  They're as opposite as fire and water.

Comment: True enough, I should have written that in quotes because I was directly mentioning what some sources call them. It's widely used as a marketing term; I suppose that's to convey the concept that yes it's prepaid, but it lets you do pretty much everything else a credit card does. Or so they are trying to tell customers!

Comment: I suppose sometimes it's used in lieu of "secured credit card" which is another thing entirely, but a less familiar concept?

Comment: Michele, secured credit cards are a well-known concept in the US, as are prepaid Visa cards.  I'd never heard of one with such a high balance before, though.  If it gets stolen... *poof* goes $10,000!

Comment: I feel like they're a hybrid product, although I'm not too familiar with the type of cards you have available. Mine comes with access to home banking, I can use it pretty much like any other card (virtual cards, block it if it's stolen, transfer balance within the card and my account or other cards, wire transfer, etc.)

Comment: Michele, nothing like that in the US.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you can try and obtain a credit card and establish credit history as a [non-US citizen/resident](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/apply-credit-card-itin-number/).

> Lucky for you, issuers can’t legally require you to provide a Social
>   Security number if you don’t have one, according to the Social
>   Security Administration. Instead, you can use an individual taxpayer
>   identification number (ITIN), which is another nine-digit identifier
>   that functions similarly to a Social Security number.

However, I would assume that you need a US address. In compliance with the [Patriot Act](http://vectertech.com/4-ways-the-patriot-act-affects-a-merchant-credit-application/), merchants are required to collect identifying information for all individuals who submit a credit application.

As far as [transferring credit score](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/apply-for-a-credit-card-without-a-social-security-number/):

> Even if you had a positive credit history in your country of origin,
>   foreign credit history can’t be transferred to the United States.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's what I thought, but I found this answer mentioning an alternative for Canadians: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/61655/63850, so I had a little hope there would be something similar for a poor European as well :)

Comment: Can you cite a source that an SSN is required for a credit score? I question the answer because even American citizens do not *have to* have a social security number. The IRS will issue an EIN instead and it does not absolve the person from paying social security taxes. It also makes applying for things that require SSNs tedious.

Comment: SSN is _not_ needed. An ITIN or EAN works too, And you can get an ITIN as a non-American living not in America - as soon as you owe taxes.

Comment: @Aganju Yes, you're correct. I updated my answer after more research.

Comment: From my limited understanding,my best chance right now would be to request an ITIN either as "Nonresident alien required to get an ITIN to claim tax treaty benefit" or "Nonresident alien filing a U.S. federal tax return". My Italian brain suggests that the first could be meant as "I would be eligible to claim tax treaty benefit if I had a US-based income", but that is probably wrong... I guess I could find some freelance work with someone in the US (I'm a programmer) and request an ITIN in relation to that income, but it seems not worth it if I'm moving in 8 months or so.